# hcitool scan does not discover any devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

My bluetooth adapter seems to work fine, I am able to discover my computer using my smarthpone, except I am not able to discover any device with my computer.

`hcitool scan` gives not result except `Scanning...`

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
        hci0    08:1E:81:A1:31:D1

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 08:1E:81:A1:31:D1  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
        RX bytes:12781 acl:168 sco:0 events:555 errors:0
        TX bytes:8818 acl:174 sco:0 commands:358 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'xubuntu-0'
        Class: 0x600100
        Service Classes: Audio, Telephony
        Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
        HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000
        LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

What can I do?